# How practical are Test Sockets?

Tags: microcontroller, packages, test-equipment

I've been looking at getting a Test Socket as of late to try and test out a bunch of old micro controllers on dead boards. However, these test sockets are very expensive when compared to their PCB-Breakout brothers which require soldering. Specifically note the LQFP 100+ test sockets where there are many pins. I'm not especially keen to soldering, because my current setup consists of a 25$ Weller soldering gun, and a toaster oven. I'm afraid that I would ruin my MCUs If I tried soldering with my setup.

That said, I'm still interested in making some prototypes with micro controllers.
My question then is; are test sockets practical for hobbyist use? At what point is it practical to buy one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are interested in trying out a new uC, buy the development board for the uC instead of purchasing sockets.

Dev boards are usually pretty cheap, are hackable and reusuable.  If things go wrong, then you can always try the supplied software that came with the dev board to test out the silicon (is it fried, or not-fried?).  It's always good to start from a situation that you can trust.

Here's a prototype with 1 custom pcb, and 2 dev boards, 1 SOIC adapter pcb, and even a 'dead bug' chip, tied together:
[image: Here's a prototype with 1 custom pcb, and 3 dev boards tied together.]

To preserve the condition of the dev boards, solder to SIP headers, and plug them in as needed.

In my opinion, one should not use (qfp) sockets for non-prototype pcb's at all.  A convincing test is to install a chip into a typical spring-loaded socket, and drop it onto its corner on your desk.  Notice how the chip is no longer aligned...

Good luck!

-Chris

Comment: What If there is no dev board for the MCU I've selected, or the socket is cheaper than the dev board?

Comment: There almost always is a dev board available.  If not the exact mcu you want, at least one in the same family.  There are also usually 3rd-party boards available as well.  However, I like buying my kits direct from the manufacturer when I can.  As for the cost, the TI dev board shown above was ~$14.

Comment: alright, but the chip that I want to test out is the AT32UC3C0512C. The only provider for a dev board of that family is Atmel itself. The dev board from atmel is 299$, whereas the socket is only ~ 100$ https://www.microchipdirect.com/productsearch.aspx?keywords=AT32UC3C-EK

Answer (score 1):

Those sockets to which you refer would require soldering as well, anyway; how do you think the socket gets attached to the board? They're useful in a few cases, and I can see them being useful for breakout boards for SOIC or TSSOP parts, but not for QFP or BGA parts; any given socket would only fit exactly one package type, whereas you can easily use an SOIC-20 socket for an SOIC-8 part.

Comment: we're both talking about sockets such as these, right? https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1Ff1lIpXXXXbwapXXq6xXFXXXl/QFP100-LQFP100-QFP-STM32F2-STM32F4-STM32-IC-Test-Socket-Programming-Adapter-0-5Pitch-Free-Shipping.jpg

Comment: Yeah. If you take that socket you've given (looks like a QFP100 socket) and try to use it for a QFP48, it's not going to work. Personally, I find that it's better, as a hobbyist, to avoid parts in QFP packages and stick to DIP, SOIC, and maybe TSSOP.

Comment: those require solder? That just looks like a bad idea.

Comment: How do you think it got attached to the board it's on in the picture? You're just moving from putting the solder on the chip to putting the solder on the socket instead.

Comment: Well, I imagine you plop the chip in there and shut the lid and it's connected to the header. Soldering the MCU to the contacts seems... out of place

Comment: There's more going on in that particular board than just a breakout board. I don't know what it is, but there's some power circuitry on it too, and more obscured by the socket. Makes me think that's a microcontroller dev board or something similar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57604/discussion-between-felthry-and-tuskiomi).